# current menu item color change

Tags: css, menuitem, submenu

i am working on a [**site**](http://beta.jointviews.com/digitalmarketing/) .as you can see the menu item **digital marketing**.when you click on it it takes you to the digital marketing page and the current menu item color changes to the given color.the problem is all the menu items under the current menu item also changes its colors.you can see that when you hover the current menu item with dropdown.

i cheked the css and found

```
ul#menu-main li.current-menu-item a {
color: #333333;
}
```

I changed it to

```
.current-menu-item a {
color: #333333;
}
```

which didn't help.what can be the problem please help!!thanks!!

Comment: Post relevant HTML in the question.

Comment: just a guess try adding the ! important attribute to the class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your css:

```
ul#menu-main li.current-menu-item > a {
    color: #333333;
}
```

Comment: hi that worked ..what was the problem actualy?

Comment: It allows you to select the children of the element.